# "Naked domain" unexpectedly closed the connection on my computer

Tags: macos, google-chrome, nginx, firefox, safari

I am experiencing `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` on all web browsers for the naked domain of my website in my computer. I don't find this issue in any other device other than my computer. The `www` version loads fine as well.

I have tried clear browser history for last 24 hours, deleted the cache and cookies. It didn't make any difference.

This is my nginx configuration.

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix:/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /assets/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/v/myappname;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/myapp/myappname;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  # <-
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }

    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Is this a device issue or something related to my nginx configuration? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out! The reason was my computer's `/etc/hosts` had a entry for the naked domain pointing to 127.0.0.1. Removing it fixed the issue.